# how to prevent 12:00:00 from becoming 00:00:00?

Tags: java, sql, date

i have a form where user enters an ad start time and an ad end time, the format of that time is "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss", then this data is push to a database.

BUT when user enters "yyyy/mm/dd 12:00:00" or basically anything 12, when i use 24 it just doesnt work, the database shows 00:00:00 for when i enter 12. how do i prevent that from happening?

```
 SplashPageValue value = new SplashPageValue();
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss");

 value.adStartDate = df.parse(fileUp.getString("adStartDate"));    
 value.adEndDate = df.parse(fileUp.getString("adEndDate"));
```

screenshots below:

the form

[image: the form]

what i see in database using SQuirreL

[image: pic]

Comment: Your question is very unclear: what does "or basically anything 12" mean, for example? How far have you got diagnosing the problem? It sounds like you should be able to come up with a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem reasonably easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but I strongly suspect the problem is just that you're parsing using the 12-hour clock. Change your format string to use HH instead of hh, and that may well just fix things:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
```

You should also consider which time zone you want to use when parsing, mind you. Personally I prefer to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) for all date and time operations in Java - including for parsing/formatting, as `SimpleDateFormat` isn't thread-safe, unlike Joda Time's parsers.

Comment: ya i was trying to let user enter a time in 24hr format, also it's a small thing so i won't use Joda Time(but i'll keep that in mind for future projects). THANKS!!!

Answer (score 3):

Your date format should be 24 hours:

`SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");`

Capital H's are 24, lowercase h are 12.

Comment: To be clear, "hh" is hours in am/pm, so "am" or "pm" parsing needs to be added to the format to work properly. That is, if not using straight out "HH".

Answer (score 2):

Use `HH` instead of `hh`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html